# What is the more efficient way to check if primary key is already used? VB.net SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql, insert, primary-key

Which is the better way to check if the primary key is already in use?

```
 Dim sql As String = "Insert into Z_SKm_Funktion_Mapping (Funktion_CSV ,Funktion_Property) values('" + MappingTextbox.Text + "','" + PropertyBox.SelectedItem + "') "
        Console.WriteLine(sql)

        Dim connectionString As String = My.Settings.SLXADRIUMDEVConnectionString

        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection)

        Try
            connection.Open()
            dataadapter.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            dataadapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

I have two solutions in mind, but I don't know if anyone of them is best.

**First one**: I could just delete the MsgBox statement in the Catch block.
Then it just runs through the code normally and does not insert the Statement.

**Second one**: I Create a Select Statement which checks if the Primary Key is already in use.

By the way: In this case Funktion_CSV is the PK

Comment: The most efficient way is to let the database handle assigin unique PKs.  You should also be using SQL Params.

Comment: Don't create race conditions, use an [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column.

Comment: This is not possible in this case. Funktion_CSV is a list which contains unofficial notations of Company functions like 'director of art'  they should be matched with a list of legit functions and saved in the table. This is why every function should be unique in the table

Comment: what do you mean "Primary Key is already use?" do you mean if "the table has PK" or "your insert contains value for PK" or... what?

Comment: The second one Farhang amary

Answer (score 3):

The best efficient way is that your primary key should be Auto-increment (with increment and seed value), and let SQL decide what will be the next value of insert records. To do this you can use IDENTITY column with Auto-increment PK in your table

If your code decides the PK values then there is the chance that multiple people doing the insert then conflict occurs and that's result in failure of insertion of records.

If you are very specific that your codes needs to decide PK(not recommended) value then better to Check first before insert and do this in Transaction So when multiple user try to insert a single time, then first records insert successfully but other records handled in catch block

Comment: Check commends above.  btw. I decided to check first instead of ignoring the exception

Comment: "Check first before insert" would also need to be in a suitable transaction otherwise you'll (if the system is intended for use by more than a single user) have a race condition. In such a case, I'd usually prefer "attempt insert, catch the error"

Comment: @steve:- you are not checking before insert, you post only insert code here

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:- agreed!

Comment: @Piyush: I only posted the insert code, because at the moment I'm thinking about which way would be the better. I know who to implement the both ways I wrote at end of the Question. So it is more a theoretical question

Comment: @steve:- Agreed, after read your question, I posted my answer with suggestion, because you are not going to implement auto-increment in sql PK column, then you are forcing with check then insert but in transaction